crypto.subtle missing in NextJs
I have just created a new NextJS app, and I can't use crypto.subtle.
It seems the global crypto variable in the browser is overwritten as shown in the screenshot. How can I fix this?


on the Crypto.subtle page it says it's only available in HTTPS, so maybe using localhost makes it not accessible? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/subtle

Heh! Got it, I think it is because I am using a host file entry. Went back to using localhost and now it works.
